# Is $E_{LBA}$ turing-recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, undecidability

I have seen [a proof that $E_{LBA}$ is not decidable](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~elomaa/teach/iTCS-11-8.pdf). But is it  at least turing recognizable? How to prove it?

*NOTE:* $E_{LBA}$ is defined as the emptiness problem for [Linear bounded automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bounded_automaton)

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a self-contained definition of $E_{LBA}$?   Also, what are your thoughts?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: sure, see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read the definitions, hence I am not an expert on LBAs, but I think that the non-emptiness problem $\overline{E_{LBA}}$ is r.e., so the emptiness problem $E_{LBA}$ can not be r.e., otherwise it would be decidable.

To see why $\overline{E_{LBA}}$ is r.e., notice that to certify that an $LBA$ has nonempty language it suffices to exhibit a word $w$ and a trace $t$ proving that $w$ is accepted by the $LBA$. So, a semidecider only has to enumerate all such pairs $(w,t)$, and (effectively) check for each pair if it proves the $LBA$'s language nonempty.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, r.e. stand for?

Comment: @Joezer r.e. = RE = recursively enumerable, also known as c.e. = computably enumerable, also known as semi-decidable or recognizable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language). Way too many names for the same concept.

Comment: how to you make sure that the Enumerator you depend on exists? (a friend argued the other way around, meaning that in fact Elba is r.e.)

Comment: @Joezer I describe above how to build a semidecider. It is a standard result that there is a semidecider iff there is an enumerator: any computability book should have that proof. Anyway, it suffices to enumerate all the triples $(LBA,w,t)$, and when $t$ proves that $w$ is accepted by $LBA$, output the $LBA$ description.